# jquery doesn't append element to the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

**SOLVED!! 
css img display:none was in confilct with newly added element.
many thanks to everybody.**

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link type="text/css" href="galerina.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="galerina">
            <img class="img1" src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img class="img2" src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img class="img3" src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img class="img4" src="images/4.jpg" alt=""/>
            <p/>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="galerina.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div.galerina{
    max-width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

div.galerina img{
    margin: auto;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.galerina img.img1{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
    $("div.galerina").each(function(){
    var gal=$(this);
    var size=$(gal).children("img").size();
    var i=0;

    $(gal).children("img").each(function(){
    var img=$(this);
    $(gal).append("<img src='images/bullet.png'/>").click(function(){
        img.stop().animate({opacity:0},300);
        img.css({display:none});
    })
})
})
```

there are no bullets at the page load?? why??

Comment: `$(img.parent())` looks wrong. Try `$(img).parent()` instead. Also consider caching `$(this)` instead of plain `this`, which doesn't really save any function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are many things you can do to make that code better. Avoid caching values you can access directly, as I said in my comment, and learn to use methods like [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) instead of doing all the work yourself.

With a little refactoring along these guidelines (and if I properly understand what you're trying to achieve), your code becomes:

```
$("div.galerina").each(function() {
    $(this).children("img").before("<img src='images/bullet.png'/>")
           .click(function() {
        $(this).prev().andSelf().fadeOut(300);
    });
});
```

Comment: many thanks i will make use of this. anyways conflict was in css img{display:none}. i made it work

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do

```
var img=$(this);
```

to get the JQuery wrapper so that the parent call works

Comment: 3nigma - not when I answered it wasn't ;) daniel: will look

Comment: daniel: why would the bullets be shown when display:none is added? or I am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("div.galerina").each(function(){
    var gal=$(this);
    var size=gal.children("img").size();
    var i=0;
    gal.children("img").each(function(){
        var img=$(this);
        img.parent().append(
        '<img src="images/bullet.png" alt="" />').click(
            function(){
                 $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0},300);
                 $(this).css({"display":"none"});
        });
    });
});
```